# Trouble Installing Google Cloud SDK on Windows 8

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-8, installation

Following Instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/

**1.
Download the Cloud SDK archive using the above button and unpack it by right-clicking google-cloud-sdk.zip file and selecting Extract All.
2.
Launch google-cloud-sdk\install.bat script and follow the installation prompts.
3.
Restart your Command Prompt (cmd.exe) session, and authenticate to Google Cloud Platform by running gcloud auth login.**

When I run install.bat it says CLOUDSDK_PYTHON should be set up to point to Python Executable.  I downloaded Python34 and it was installed in the default directory C:\Python34.

So I created a new ENvironment Variable CLOUDSDK_PYTHON and set it to C:\Python34\, but it says cannot recognize the directory.  What could be the issue?

Does anybody have step by step instructions on how to install Google SDK on Windows 8 ?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, but now my problem is solved:

1. Create new Path to User Variables, not to System Variables.
2. Write down `C:\Python##` in lowercase.

Now it should work.

Try my steps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need Python 2.7.x version:)